# Trying to configure two USB drives for Samba server, permissions allow access to one but not the other on PC?

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi, samba

On my raspberry pi 3 that has Samba and Ntfs-3g running Raspian I have two USB drives mounted to two folders (from **lsblk**)

[image]

Then I have added the following code to the bottom of the samba configure file smb.conf:

[image]

Now Whenever I try to access on my windows PC, I can access the one of the USB drives, but then I am unable to access my other USB due to permissions

[image]

The silver directory works. however toshiba does not
Is there anyway to have both USB drives accessible at the same time?

Permissions

[image]